# Optimizing the weighted sum of sparse matrices

Tags: matlab, performance, matrix, optimization, sparse-matrix

I welcome any help for the following code optimization problem:

I have a collection of N sparse matrices of identical sizes (`[s1 s2]`) stored in a cell array `A` and a corresponding number of scalar weights stored in an vector `w`. I want to compute the sum of all the matrices in `A` weighted by the values stored in `w`. Through the iterations of my program, only the values in `w`change. I can therefore compute a priori the number of non-zero elements in my result and pre-allocate some memory for it using `spalloc`.
For the moment I have something like:

```
result = spalloc(s1,s1,number_of_non_zero);
for i=1:N
    result = result + w(i)*A{i};
end
```

I really need do optimize this part which for the moment takes most of the computing time in my program (checked with the profiling tools).
Some additional information:
-The above code runs millions of times so even minor improvements are welcome.
-The matrices in `A` come from a finite element code (1D or 2D)
-I have no problem moving away from the cell structure if I can save some time (like using  `cell2mat(A)`)

Thank you for any hint on how to speed up this part of the code.

A.

Comment: Operations on sparse arrays are generally slow. Can you afford having all A as full arrays? Alternatively, do all A have the same pattern of non-zeros?

Comment: This loop is part of a multidimensional PDE solver, so full matrices is not an option (for memory and computation time). You can assume that the sparsity pattern is the same. Apart from summing those matrices, I solve linear systems using `result` and perform matrix-vector products with the different matrices of `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for sure if this solution will be more computationally-efficient, but it's something else to try...

If you really have to represent your matrices as sparse (i.e. full matrices take up too much memory) and the [built-in sparse representation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sparse.html) in MATLAB isn't giving you the performance you desire, then you can try representing the sparse matrices in a different way. Specifically, you can represent them as N-by-3 matrices where the first two columns contain the row and column indices into the matrix for all the non-zero values and the third column contains the non-zero values. You can convert your data to this form using the function [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html) like so:

```
for iMatrix = 1:numel(A)
  [r,c,v] = find(A{iMatrix});
  A{iMatrix} = [r c v];
end
```

Each time you need to compute the weighted sum of these matrices, you first need to multiply the values by the weights:

```
B = A;  %# Store a temporary copy of A
for iMatrix = 1:numel(B)
  B{iMatrix}(:,3) = w(iMatrix).*B{iMatrix}(:,3);
end
```

Then, you can compute the final sum using the function [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html):

```
B = vertcat(B{:});  %# Convert B from a cell array to an N-by-3 matrix
result = accumarray(B(:,1:2),B(:,3));
```

The variable `result` in this case will be a full matrix. If you need `result` to be a sparse matrix, you can add extra arguments in the call to [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html) like so:

```
result = accumarray(B(:,1:2),B(:,3),[],[],[],true);
```

Comment: this looks like the only alternative to me given the present matlab capabilities. Haven't had a chance yet to run tests on real cases though.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert `A` to a matrix instead of a cell array then you could vectorize the loop using some [RESHAPE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html) and [REPMAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) acrobatics. Pretend we have the following data:

```
>> A(:,:,1) = [1 0 0; 0 0 2; 0 0 0];
>> A(:,:,2) = [3 0 1; 0 3 0; 0 1 0]

A(:,:,1) =

     1     0     0
     0     0     2
     0     0     0


A(:,:,2) =

     3     0     1
     0     3     0
     0     1     0

>> w = [2; 3]

w =

     2
     3
```

Reshape `w` so that you can do an element-by-element multiplication and then sum:

```
>> w = reshape(w, [1 1 length(w)])

w(:,:,1) =

     2


w(:,:,2) =

     3

>> w = repmat(w, [size(A,1) size(A,2) 1])

w(:,:,1) =

     2     2     2
     2     2     2
     2     2     2


w(:,:,2) =

     3     3     3
     3     3     3
     3     3     3

>> w .* A

ans(:,:,1) =

     2     0     0
     0     0     4
     0     0     0


ans(:,:,2) =

     9     0     3
     0     9     0
     0     3     0

>> sum(w .* A, 3)

ans =

    11     0     3
     0     9     4
     0     3     0
```

Comment: Instead of using `repmat` on `w`, you can use `bsxfun`: `out = bsxfun(@times,A,w)` using the reshaped `w`.

Comment: @Jonas and @b3 The problem is that the matrices in A are sparse and ND-sparse arrays are not supported. (error message upon reshape(cell2mat(A),....)

Comment: @Adrien: You should run some tests to see which compromise leads to the best results. It may be that using regular matrices instead of sparse ones is better but means you have to do a handful of loops of a vectorized algorithm over blocks of matrices. It really all depends on the balance of your memory usage vs. execution time requirements.

Comment: believe me when I say that full matrices are not an option. I i simply make a mistake and input one of those matrices as non-sparse, the computation time explodes. I can have up to several hundredth of those matrices and I need to perform matrix vector products, sum those matrices and then solve a linear system with the result of this sum as the left hand side of the system. As this is performed a lot full matrices kill you (N^3 complexity for linear system solution, N^2 for matrix vector product).